# Adding the first new DataGridView row does not update the DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, csvhelper

When I add a new row to a DataGridView, the row is not saved to the DataView or DataTable. But when I add another row after that, that row is added. The first new row is completely ignored. I have no clue why. Please help.

```
private string _filePath;
private DataTable _dataTable;
private DataView _defaultView;

public StringRecords(string fileName)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _dataTable = FileManager.Populate(filePath);
    _dataTable.TableName = filePath;
    _defaultView = new DataView(_dataTable);
    dataGridRecords.DataSource = _defaultView;
}

private void dataGridRecords_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    FileManager.SaveDataTableToCsv(_dataTable, filePath);
}

public static void SaveDataTableToCsv(DataTable source, string fileName)
{
    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(fileName, false))
    {
        var config = new CsvConfiguration { Delimiter = "|", HasHeaderRecord = false };
        using (var writer = new CsvWriter(stream, config))
        {
            var records = ToStringRecordList(source);

            writer.WriteRecords(records);
        }
    }
}
```

Adding the first new row produces this debug output only:

```
Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'.
```

I've dumped the DataTable and DataView objects. The first new row isn't added to either object.

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I find out what's happening to the first new row?